# Expresión regular Javascript para validar número telefónico

Tags: javascript, html, regex, input

quiero armar una expresión regular en Javascript para validar un número telefónico de celular URUGUAYO.
Mi idea es que la validación conste de tres condiciones. La primera y obvio: es que tenga que ser números. La segunda: que tenga 9 dígitos exactamente, ni más ni menos. La tercera: que tenga sí o sí que comenzar con los números 09.

O sea, quiero armar una expresión regular que verifique que el imput tenga 9 dígitos y que además empiece necesariamente por 09. El problema es que no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo y no encontré por ningún lado ningún tutorial o página que me lo explique bien.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: La expresión regular es muy sencilla: /^09[0-9]{7}$/gm

Answer (score 2):

Basándome en la expresión regular que te he puesto en el comentario previo y en el código que te genera automáticamente la web [regex101](https://regex101.com/):

```javascript
const regex = /^09[0-9]{7}$/gm;
/* Asigna a esta variable el valor que quieres verificar */
const str = `095458714`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: El problema de copiar el código generado por regex101.com es que trae líneas innecesarias para este caso puntual. `/^09\d{7}$/` es suficiente, sin modificadores. Y no es necesario comprobar que no haya coincidencias de longitud 0. Además, todo el bucle es innecesario, con un simple `if` se puede ver si coincidió o no.

Answer (score -1):

Esta expresión debería funcionar:

```
// Expresión: /^[09][0-9]{1,7}$/

if (/^[09][0-9]{1,7}$/.test('091234567')){
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}
```

Descripción de la expresión regular:

- `[09]` = Caracteres iniciales.
- `[0-9]` = Caracteres permitidos.
- `{1,7}` = Números restantes para llegar a los 9 caracteres